# Problema con Estructura de datos en C - Arboles

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo un problema con la definicion y creacion de estructuras de datos para usar arboles. Las estructuras que debo usar si o si y no debo cambiar es la siguiente:

```
#define INT 1024
#define CHAR 1025
#define STRING 1032
#define LIST 1033
#define SET 1034

typedef struct dataType* dataPtr;
typedef struct stringType* stringPtr;
typedef struct charType* charPtr;


struct dataType{
    int nodeType;
    dataPtr dato;
    dataPtr sig;
};

struct stringType{
    int nodeType;
    char valor;
};
struct charType{
    int nodeType;
    char valor;
};
```

Cuando voy a crear el arbol de la siguiente manera:

```
dataPtr aux;

aux=(dataPtr*)malloc(sizeof(dataPtr));
```

Y al probar la funcion en el main (o sea al compilar) me tira error de Windows y esta sugerencia:

" return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]"

Alguien sabe como lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataPtr` ya es un puntero (fijate el typedef que dice `dataPtr` equivale a `dataType *`). Por otro lado, el tamaño que querés reservar es el de `dataType`, por lo tanto al `malloc` deberías pasarle el tamaño de esta estructura.

La línea que te falla debería quedar así:

```
aux=(dataPtr)malloc(sizeof(dataType));
```

Si bien `dataPtr *` es un tipo de datos válido, este equivale a `dataType **` (puntero a puntero).